# Allowing Snowflake to unload data into AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My goal is to unload data from Snowflake to AWS S3.

I've followed this documentation and have set up everything except Step2.6 where it's asking for "Account ID". I've temporarily set it up with my own AWS account ID. Where do I find Snowflake's Account ID.
[Configuring a Snowflake Storage Integration to Access Amazon S3](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html#step-2-create-the-iam-role-in-aws)

**Step 2.6 says "In the Account ID field, enter your own AWS account ID temporarily. Later, you will modify the trusted relationship and grant access to Snowflake."**
How do I get this one?

I've read this doc page about Account Identifiers but this doesn't seem to be the right id:
[Snowflake Account Identifiers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html#using-an-account-name-as-an-identifier)

Any idea how can I can get that Account ID so I can allow Snowflake to upload data into the S3 bucket.

Comment: "Later" means you should scroll down on the page. E.g. to step 4.

Comment: @luk2302 Step4 it's giving me the IAM_USER_ARN and EXTERNAL_ID which are used for role trust relationships. I don't see the account id there.
Or am I missing something? Which property displayed by desc integration s3_int; are you reffering to?

Answer (score 1):

The "Account ID" here does not refer to the Snowflake Account information bu the AWS ID for the tenant where you are setting up the integration.

Comment: I'm confused on which tenant is that. can you please be a little more specific on this? :)
so what you mean is that this Account ID I need to provide is not related to Snowflake at all? where would I find it?

Comment: This is the tenant to which the integration is being set up. Details to get your AWS Account ID are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html